# Symfony2 No route found for GET/add

Tags: symfony

i am trying to add some value to db via entitiy (i'm studying examples). 
I crated a local route for createAction which is located in DefaultController. But when i try to go to page, it says no router.

Here is my example code. How can i solve this. Thanks for help.

```
/*Local Routes:

            acme_store_homepage:
            pattern:  /hello/{name}
            defaults: { _controller: AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index }
            acme_store_product:
            pattern: /add
            defaults: { _controller: AcmeStoreBundle:Default:create }
            */

            /* app Routes:
            acme_store:
            resource: "@AcmeStoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
            prefix:   /

            */


            /* 

            Default Controller

            */



            <?php

            namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;

            use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
            use Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product;
            use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

            class DefaultController extends Controller
            {
            public function indexAction($name)
            {
            return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
            }

            public function createAction()
            {
            $product = new Product();
            $product->setName("SomeProduct");
            $product->setPrice("1000");
            $product->setDescription("Bla bla bla.");


            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();

            return new Response('Product id: '.$product->getId());
            }
            }



            //Running http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/add is throwing an exception:  No route found for "GET /demo/add" 
            //Running http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello/World is Fine...
```

Comment: you sure this is working http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/hello/World ?? or is this working  http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/World ??

Comment: @basantrijal yes i am sure. it works and gives source code too

Comment: Here `acme_store:
            resource: "@AcmeStoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
            prefix:   /` u havent define prefix and in `acme_store_product:
            pattern: /add
            defaults: { _controller: AcmeStoreBundle:Default:create }` u defined only pattern:
try:
localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/add

Comment: @basantrijal thanks. if i want to see it in demo what will i do?  is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
acme_store: 
      resource: "@AcmeStoreBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" 
      prefix: /
```

You haven't define prefix and in

```
acme_store_product: 
         pattern: /add 
         defaults: { _controller: AcmeStoreBundle:Default:create }
```

You defined only :

```
pattern: /add
```

try: `localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/add`

and if you want to access it by /demo/add and /demo/hello/world add

```
prefix:/demo
```

in app routes

Comment: it works but prefix:/demo. i think it wont seem in demo page.

Comment: for /demo only to work add route with pattern:/ in bundle route like
`acme_store_homepage:
            pattern:  /
            defaults: { _controller: AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index }`

Comment: OK. i understand now. DemoBundle and StoreBundle are different. they have both hello application. i am working on StoreBundle and trying to access DemoBundle and this was wrong thing. Thanks for help.